# Solve this by converting sentences to clausal form?

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence

If:

$E\land R \implies B$
$E\implies R\lor P\lor L$
$K\implies B$
$\lnot(L\land B)$
$P\implies \lnot K$

Which of the following can't be deducted?

1. $E\land P$
2. $K \land E \implies R$
3. $L \land P \implies\lnot K$
4. $L \implies\lnot(K \land E)$

Comment: Start converting the premises to clausal form.

Comment: what's the main rules to do this? any resources?

Comment: Maybe your textbook... See also [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic))

Comment: In order to check underivability (it can't be deducted) the simplest approach is to check with truth assignment. Example with 1): assume that $E \land P$ is false and check if all premises are still true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use the following resolution rule

$\frac{a \vee b, \quad \neg a \vee c}
{b \vee c}$

multiple times to deduce 2, 3, 4 from the following (given) knowledgebase

(a) $\lnot E\lor \lnot R \lor B$
(b) $\lnot E \lor R\lor P\lor L$
(c) $\lnot K \lor B$
(d) $\lnot L \lor  \lnot B$
(e) $\lnot P \lor \lnot K$

From (c) and (d) we can deduce (f), i.e.,

$B \lor \lnot K, \quad \lnot B \lor  \lnot L$

---

(f) $\lnot K \lor \lnot L$

From (f) we can deduce $\lnot K \lor \lnot L \lor \lnot P$,
which means we can deduce $\lnot (L \land P) \lor \lnot K$, i.e.,

3. $L \land P \implies\lnot K$

Also, From (f) we can deduce $\lnot K \lor \lnot L \lor \lnot E$,
which means we can deduce $\lnot L \lor \lnot (K \land E)$, i.e.,

4. $L \implies\lnot (K \land E)$

Again, from (b) and (f) we can deduce (g)

$L\lor \lnot E \lor R\lor P,  \quad \lnot L \lor \lnot K$

---

(g) $\lnot E \lor R\lor P\lor \lnot K$

Now, from (g) and (e)

$P\lor \lnot E \lor R\lor \lnot K, \quad \lnot P \lor \lnot K$

---

$\lnot E \lor R\lor \lnot K$

which means we have deduced $\lnot (K \land E) \lor R$, i.e.,

2. $K \land E \implies R$

Thus we have proved that 2, 3, 4 can be deduced from the knowledgebase provided.

We can see 1 is not necessarily TRUE even if (a)-(e) holds TRUE,
e.g., Let K=False, L=False, E=False, P=False, then (a)-(e) holds TRUE but 1 does not hold TRUE.